# Why are some fonts being rendered hollow on Chrome?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, fonts

I have been using Chrome for a while now, and few days back the font rendering
(I assume it is specifically for the bold fonts) began to become hollow. 
I tried resetting Chrome flags to default, but that did not help.

[image: A sample image to show the error]

I have installed over a hundred font packs in the past week or so,
and I can't pinpoint exactly when this issue started showing up.

How can I identify the source of this problem, and how do I solve it?

Comment: Have you recently installed any font packs? Sometimes they can conflict.

Comment: I have installed over a hundred font packs in the past week or so. And I can't pinpoint exactly when this issue started showing up

Comment: There is most likely a font pack that conflicts. I had this issue before when i downloaded a font for an assignment and it ended up changing my windows font! Since you installed so many, your best bet is probably to uninstall them and install the ones you need one by one.

Comment: Did you try other browser(s) e.g. _MSIE_ (`iexplore.exe`) or _Edge_?  The same or another look?

Comment: Sorry, the [Logistic Regression with a Neural Network mindset](https://github.com/Kulbear/deep-learning-coursera/blob/master/Neural%20Networks%20and%20Deep%20Learning/Logistic%20Regression%20with%20a%20Neural%20Network%20mindset.ipynb) document does not work in _MSIE_. Please note that GitHub no longer supports Internet Explorer…

Comment: Did you install any outline fonts or fonts containing an outline version (those are fonts designed to look like that)?  It may be selecting the outline font or version in place of bold.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same exact problem.
Except I only installed one set of fonts recently, so if you're using the same set, then this should help you out.

I recently downloaded a font pack called Helvetica Neue from Cufon Fonts, [and here are some of the styles it includes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDYJX.png).
Look familiar?

If you're using this font, I recommend just uninstalling it completely by opening your File Explorer from the Start Menu, then go to [Local Disc (C:) >> Windows >> Fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX4YX.png), and search for Helvetica Neue and delete it all.

Sorry this is the best I can do for you, but at least it will fix your website fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found that the offending font was **Helvetica 75 Bold Outline**

[image]

So I tried to delete it and I was not allowed to do so!

[image]

*(please ignore that I capture the screenshot for the wrong font, oops!)*

I could even navigate to my fonts folder at `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` and see the font, but not delete it here either!

[image]

---

### SOLUTION: How to delete the font file

After lots of searching and trying things, the following worked for allowing me to delete this font!

In the registry editor navigate to:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`

and here you can find the font.

[image]

- Delete it from the registry.
- Now go back to the folder at `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` and you can now delete the actual font file!

Answer (score -1):

its Helvetica Neue Bold font.
Uninstall it and you are fine.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in a [previous answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1454262/10259) and does not add to that answer. As per the [Help Center on what answers are deleted](/help/deleted-answers) this answer could be deleted.